# Another question about continuity and inverse maps

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, inverse

In my studies I came across the reversibility of strictly monotonic functions.

**The sentence states[S]:**

**[S]** The function $f$ is on any intervall $I$ strictly growing. Then there exists the inverse $f^{-1}$ on $f(I)$, which is also strictly growing and continuous.

If $f$ is also continuous, so $f(I)$ has to be an intervall with (sometimes even infinitly many) boundries, $\inf f$ and $\sup f$. In this case $f(I)$ is exactly than left or right closed, when $I$ is left or right closed.

This also holds in the same way for strictly decreasing.

---

I had to show in an exercise that with $f$ being strictly monotonic on an intervall $I$.
Which implies $f^{-1}$ being also strictly monotonic, that its wrong to assume $f$ being continuous.

Thing is: **[S]** states, that $f^{-1}$ is continuous and also strictly monotonic on $f(I)$

But if we now call $g:=f^{-1}$ than there exists $g^{-1}$ since $g$ also fullfills the requirements. And $g^{-1}=f$

But than $g^{-1}=f$ should be also strictly monotonic (which is indeed the case) and continuous on $g(f(I))=g(g^{-1}(I))=I$

But Im $100$% sure im pretty damn wrong somewhere..

Okey my questions more precisesly:

**[S]** is writen in my textbook as a lemma. And it doenst require $f$ which **[S]** refers to, to be continuous. And I cant think of why when $f$ isnt continuous and strictly (for example) growing on an intervall $I$, why $f^{-1}$ will also strictly grow but be continuous on the given intervall $f(I)$.. I mean as you can see above, thats the way how I think about it right now, and if I would be correct (which cant be true) than $f$ has to be continuous in order for $f^{-1}$ to be continuous (and ofc $f$ and $f^{-1}$ both are strictly (for example) growing)

Can someone help? :)

---

Picture of exercise and of **[S]**: (as wished in the comments :))

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you see a contradiction here? That too with 100% confidence!

Comment: Noo you misunderstood me. I didnt try to proof anything yet :) I just wrote down my thinking path.. and I end at a place where it doesnt make sense for $f$ not to be continuous..

Comment: so my path is wrong obviously?

Comment: My problem is.. I thought when $f^{-1}$ is always continuous, then why shouldnt $f$ not be? Since in some sense $f$ is the inverse of $f^{-1}$ again. Somewhere in my thinking process is a big Oof..

Comment: I did :) But its german :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intuitions will become better as  you see more examples.

My translation of your "S", where I have stuck in a phrase in square brackets.

> 37.1  Inversion theorem for strictly monotone functions:
>    Let the function $f$ be strictly increasing on a given interval $I$, which may be finite or infinite. Then its inverse function $f^{-1}$,  defined on $f(I)$, is strictly monotone and continuous [on $f(I)$]...

For example: this $f$ is  strictly monotone increasing function on $I=\mathbb R$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x&\text{ for } x\le0\\x+1&\text{ for } x>0.\end{cases}$$
It has a jump discontinuity at $x=0$.  In this case $f(I)=(-\infty,0]\cup(1,\infty)$, and the inverse function $g$ given, for $y\in f(I)$, by
$$
g(y)=\begin{cases}y&y\le0\\y-1&y>1.\end{cases}$$
As advertised, this is continuous and strictly increasing on the disconnected set $f(I)$.  There is an extension of $g$ to all of $\mathbb R$, namely
$$
\hat g(y)=\begin{cases}y&y\le0\\0&0<y\le 1\\y-1&y>1.\end{cases}$$
This function is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ but not strictly monotone there.  A careless reader of MSE (such as myself), or of the textbook, might assume $f^{-1}$ is this $\hat g$; but your textbook author really wants $g$.

The question posed in the second snapshot is

> 3. Suppose the function $f$ is strictly monotone on the  interval $I$. Then, as we know, $f^{-1}$ is strictly monotone.  Why is it an incorrect application of the inversion theorem to conclude that the inverse of $f^{-1}$, which is $f$, is also continuous?

The answer is, $f^{-1}$ is  defined on $f(I)$, which might not be an interval, but a disjoint union of intervals, as in the example I gave above.  The inversion theorem applies only to functions defined on an interval, but not to functions defined on disjoint unions of intervals.

Comment: But $[S]$ states $f^{-1}$ is always continuous, disregarding weither $f$ os continuous.. and $g(y)$ is discontinuous on $[-1,1]$ or do I mix something up?

Comment: Ohhhh ofc $g(y)$ isnt discontinuous, sorry! Thank you this helped alot to fix some tornados in my head :)

Comment: Hmm but $g(y) $ also needs to strictly grow..

Comment: I have changed my answer; you might want to change your vote.  Or, more usefully, rewrite your question to make clear what you are really asking.

Comment: No the textbook is saying [S] and then in the exercise section the author asks me why $f$ doesnt need to be continuous

Comment: Its Harro Heuser page 231 (german edition) (17th edition) If I quoted it wrong it might be a problem with my translation skills.. I can try to quote it better.. If you dont own the book. Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: Ill Update [S] with (my try) to completle mathc the quote

Comment: And in my exercises I had exactly to show: Let $f$ be strictly monotonic on an intervall $I$. Then is, as we know, also $f^{-1}$. strictly monotonic. Why is it a wrong  assumption, if you would conclude that $f$ has to be continuous

Comment: [S] states, that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and the exercise ask me to show, that $f$. doesnt have to be, and there comes my originial "thinking path" which let me asking

Comment: I have rewritten my answer.  The problem boils down to understanding the precise definition of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: excellent, now everything is clear. Thank you so much for investing time to decrypt my blindness :)